# MySQL - how to store "other"?

Tags: mysql, database-design

How to store "other" text?

In summary, I have too many of these kinds of fields (like hundreds?):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H81O.png

I don't know an appropriate way to handle this.

If I store only text of these options, then I will have data redundancy and no foreign key. Maybe foreign key does not matter since I am allowing users to store "other" anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a radio list where only one option could be specified then I'd use one column and store the selected value if something other than "other" were picked and the value from the free-text box otherwise.

As it appears that your application allows selecting multiple item (which may or may not include "other") then you need to store a list of possible options per form. A boolean per check box may be inefficient, but do avoid a comma separated list (i.e. a field called "foods" in which you store "rice,soup" in the example you give) as that can make reporting (amongst other things) difficult.

How I *would* go about storing this data would depend on the amount on the rest of the data set: there are a couple of methods that are optimal for different circumstances. Could you update the question to give more details about the application and its data?

Comment: +1 for the comma separated list recommendation. I'd have a table called other_item -  and then foreign key that into the standard_item table. Bit of a pain at the beginning adding all the "other items", but once that's done - you'll have far fewer problems. Under **NO** circumstances, let staff input text directly - you'll have phone numbers/addresses - **all** sorts of rubbish.

Comment: @Vérace This food thing was just an example. Storing text makes quite some sense in the scenarios I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes, but don't allow "ordinary" employees to enter free text - a recipe (if you'll pardon the pun) for disaster. Put in place a monitored procedure for entering data into this "other_item" table. Whether it's food or whatever widget you sell, have a procedure and a clear chain of command for controlling the entering of the data, with periodic reviews  - a report once a month on newly added items to be vetted by a  manager. It may seem like overkill, but it's better than a database full of garbage!

Comment: @Vérace These are not ordinary employees. They are highly trained staff members. If I were to have items pre-populated, I would have to load entire dictionary and still get complaint that they need to enter phrases!

Comment: Just put a system of some sort in place - I don't care how highly trained they are - if you let people enter free text, it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: David, are you suggesting to not have foreign keys then (if you're suggesting simply storing text of these options - whether other is selected or regular is selected)?

Comment: @user3692125: You can still have proper referential integrity if the items in the lists are stored in a list options table - you would just need to extend the content of that table as users add things via the "other" box(es). I'm wary of going into further detail without knowing more about the data and application though: I could end up suggesting something quite sub-optimal.

Comment: David, the application has too many groups (~25) of checkboxes. Each of these groups have about 3-6 options (checkboxes). Some of these groups have "other" option and some don't. Most of these groups only allow one checkbox to be checked per group (so works more like a radio button) but a couple of these groups may allow multiple selections. Please ask more questions if not enough detail.